# Ubuntu is slow this morning

Tags: 16.04

This morning, my Ubuntu 16.04 is behaving strangely.

My mouse movements sometimes show a little lag, the applications too are a little slower when I open them. Even when I type, sometimes there is a little lag before the letters appear. Everything is slow basically. I haven't changed anything as far as I know. Could this be an update that my computer doesn't like?

I've rebooted the machine, but I'm not sure where else to start to figure it out. Any suggestions most welcome.

---

Update:

It seems that the problem only occurs when my laptop is connected to the power adapter - the original HP one.

Is also seems too coincidental that I have recently been using a new non-HP power adaptor with the laptop when I use it at home. I think this is the problem.

Comment: I would start typing `top` and checking if any process as unusual activity.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be.  Firefox is at the top,  using about 5%.

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated a feature in the bios that would affect your CPU, like power saving, hyper threading?

Check if it works better when plugged in. (If you are using a laptop).

Kind regards

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the bios and it was running fine yesterday. Also, it has been plugged in the whole time - actually, when I unplug the power cord, things seem to run as normal! Is this possible?